# fill weight paint to selected vertecies

Tags: weight-painting

[image]

hello  I would like to know the way to fill red color to all the selected vertices at once.

[image]

weight gradient (ctrl + drag) is effective to paint larger area at once, but are there more simple ways?

thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to edit mode, select the desired vertices, go to properties window, Vertex Groups tab (green vertices triangle), select the desired vertex group, choose the weight value (default 1.0 in your example) and click the "assign" button.

Comment: Thank you very much.